# Check if word contains substring in Java Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

If I want to check all words that contain the substring DEF, would this be the right approach:

```
^.*[D][E][F].*$
```

Also is there an easy rule when negating regexes, i.e. modifying the above to identify strings that don't contain DEF

EDIT: I know this doesn't require regexes, but for my purposes it does.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This works too:

```
^.*DEF.*$
```

It checks, if *the whole String* contains the substring "DEF" at least once. But for trivial expressions like this:

```
str.contains("DEF");
```

does the same.

Comment: @LouisRhys, `^` and `$` stand for the beginning and end of the string, respectively. If you are using java's `String.matches(String)`, you don't need to use them though, since this method returns true only if the regular expression matches the *entire* input string.

Answer (score 10):

Why not just use `str.contains("DEF")` and `!str.contains("DEF")`?

Comment: The built in contains() method just looks along the bytes in the string for an occurrence of chars D, E and F in that order, you could consider it a brute force search. E.g. a string of 100 chars would be "checked" up to ~97 times for that sequence. Regular expressions are a very, very different animal.

Comment: Learn more about string searching/matching at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: "Why not just use..." because I have to use a regex in my situation. As for answering the question, this might be a better answer for a lot of situations, but you asked "Why not" so here is why not...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `DEF` as your regexp. To identify strings that don't contain it, simply return the strings that don't match the above expression.

Comment: how would you identify using regex all words not containing a particular substring

Comment: Like I said, I'd just negate the result, so it would be `!string.matches( "DEF" );`

Comment: but i mean outside of java using just purely a regex